# Native crash at /system/lib/libart.so on lollipop android 5.0.1 samsung

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, samsung-mobile

I've an app built using cordova on google Play Store. The app works on all devices and models, except on a few Samsung devices running on android 5.0.1 (Note3 and Note4). The app crashes on launch. The crash stack trace is the following:

```
    *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/treltexx/trelte:5.0.1/LRX22C/N910CXXU1BOC5:user/release-keys'
Revision: '21'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 25267, tid: 25267, name: anari.kanariapp >>> com.kanari.kanariapp <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x7772c684
r0 00002000 r1 00005145 r2 b4d50c1d r3 00000000
r4 0f723b17 r5 7772c680 r6 00014514 r7 771f2048
r8 00001b17 r9 7771816c sl 00001fff fp b4d1b350
ip b4d50c00 sp be9e7be0 lr b4aafa45 pc b4af98c8 cpsr 000e0030

backtrace:
#00 pc 001108c8 /system/lib/libart.so (art::TypeLookupTable::Lookup(char const*) const+75)
#01 pc 000c6a41 /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::LookupClassFromImage(char const*, art::gc::space::ImageSpace*)+72)
#02 pc 000d73df /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::DefineClass(char const*, art::Handle<art::mirror::ClassLoader>, art::DexFile const&, art::DexFile::ClassDef const&)+102)
#03 pc 000d7aad /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::FindClassInPathClassLoader(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable&, art::Thread*, char const*, art::Handle<art::mirror::ClassLoader>)+484)
#04 pc 00211297 /system/lib/libart.so (art::VMClassLoader_findLoadedClass(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jobject*, _jstring*)+286)
#05 pc 0001b241 /system/framework/arm/boot.oat
```

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a problem with Samsung extensions and zipalign -z (Zopfli compression).  Remove the "-z" and the problem should go away.

Comment: Hey, Richard where I need to remove "-z" and how?

Comment: Do we have any answer here?