# Native crash in Android 7.0

Tags: android

I am seeing a lot of the below native crash which happens on Android 7.0 only. The affected devices are all from Samsumg. Any ideas what is causing this native crash or how can I debug it? Thanks.

```
backtrace:
  native: pc 000000000006bbd0  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
  native: pc 0000000000069054  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+64)
  native: pc 00000000000244b8  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+24)
  native: pc 000000000001ced4  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+52)
  native: pc 000000000042d328  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+352)
  native: pc 00000000000e4ca4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+1204)
  native: pc 000000000024a728  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art22IndirectReferenceTable17AbortIfNoCheckJNIEv+140)
  native: pc 00000000002f1df0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art22IndirectReferenceTable10GetCheckedEPv+816)
  native: pc 00000000002ee054  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt12DecodeGlobalEPv+24)
  native: pc 00000000004501dc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread13DecodeJObjectEP8_jobject+216)
  native: pc 0000000000426bc0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8ArgArray24BuildArgArrayFromVarArgsERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_6mirror6ObjectESt9__va_list+472)
  native: pc 00000000004268b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17InvokeWithVarArgsERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+356)
  native: pc 0000000000343418  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI21CallStaticVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+604)
  native: pc 0000000000004094  /system/lib64/libaudioeffect_jni.so
  native: pc 0000000000003eac  /system/lib64/libaudioeffect_jni.so
  native: pc 000000000012d114  /system/lib64/libmedia.so
  native: pc 000000000004b6bc  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android8BpBinder14reportOneDeathERKNS0_8ObituaryE+140)
  native: pc 000000000004b5e0  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android8BpBinder12sendObituaryEv+148)
  native: pc 0000000000055b14  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14executeCommandEi+832)
  native: pc 0000000000055718  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState20getAndExecuteCommandEv+156)
  native: pc 0000000000055dc0  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14joinThreadPoolEb+72)
  native: pc 0000000000072df4  /system/lib64/libbinder.so
  native: pc 0000000000012430  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+272)
  native: pc 00000000000a5120  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+116)
  native: pc 000000000006885c  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+196)
  native: pc 000000000001e118  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
```

Comment: Native crashes means error in teh software. It may be a call you make, but it can also be the system cannot handle your app. Most likely, you make a call to an API that is bugged. As this is a native crash, you cannot fix it by patching the system. If it is a call to something related to the system that causes the crash, I recommend you add log tags before and after every method, field or any calls in the activity in question. Figure out what method/field causes the crash, and do it until you find the exact call that causes the crash

Comment: @LunarWatcher, thanks for the suggestion. The problem here is that this crash has only been reported in the Google Developer Console. I am not able to reproduce it on my testing devices.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727990/native-crash-at-system-lib-libart-so-on-lollipop-android-5-0-1-samsung. May this be zipalign again?