# Running zipalign with zopfli recompression after building APK from command line to make it smaller

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, zipalign, zopfli

As mentioned in [Google Developers' article](https://medium.com/google-developers/smallerapk-part-1-anatomy-of-an-apk-da83c25e7003), it is now possible to recompress APK files using zopfli by running `zipalign -z`. In my case, a 200 KB reduction is observed on a 5.1 MB APK file.

Normally I build the APK using a custom shell script, by running `gradle assembleRelease`.

I want to run `zipalign -z <the final apk>` after the above command. However, `zipalign` is located in the `build-tools/<build tools version>` directory, which I can't locate it except by pulling out the `<build tools version>` from the `build.gradle` file and constructing the path manually.

Is it possible to run `zipalign` using the `gradle` command that automatically run the `zipalign` on the correct `build-tools` directory without me having to reconstuct the path?

For example a command such as `gradle runBuildTools zipalign -z $FINAL_APK $FINAL_APK.out`

Comment: **NOTE**: Google **no longer recommends Zopfli compression for APKs**: *"Update: Previously this article contained a section on recompressing files in your APK using a stronger compression algorithm called Zopfli. This feature is now being removed from our build tools as of Android Studio 2.2 and is no longer recommended, as it might interfere with future plans for making Play Store incremental updates even smaller."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [article](https://medium.com/google-developers/smallerapk-part-1-anatomy-of-an-apk-da83c25e7003#1646) that you linked to has been updated with the gradle task to add the zopfli compression to the end of the assembleRelease task.

```
//add zopfli to variants with release build type
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.assemble.doLast {
            println "Zopflifying... it might take a while"
            exec {
                commandLine output.zipAlign.zipAlignExe,'-f','-z', '4', output.outputFile.absolutePath , output.outputFile.absolutePath.replaceAll('\\.apk$', '-zopfli.apk')
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! That is exactly what I needed.

Comment: For future readers, it's not recommended to use Zopfli compression anymore. Please check the article that is linked in the answer for more information.