# signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR)

Tags: android, google-play, samsung-mobile, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I'm getting about 50 crashes daily. I'm not using any NDK in the app. This is crashing **only on Samsung devices**. Maximum on Samsung J2.
I'm not using zopfli. I'm using android app bundle. This is happening on **android 5** devices only.

This is all I have to go on.

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR)
art::ArtField_getNameNative(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)


*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.packagename <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000020d9d2  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtField_getNameNative(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+281)
  #00  pc 00000000000000e7  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat
```